# Track google calendar subscriptions

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there a way to actively tell which email addresses or google/iCal accounts have added/subscribed to a google calendar? I would like to keep track of how many and which email addresses use it or if they have unsubscribed. Currently, users can add the calendar either to their google calendar or their iCal. I own this calendar and have full access to its features should this be required.